# Forwarding a HttpPut request with PutAsync

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How do I forward a HttpPut request in c# please?

This is what I have so far but I would like to change SendAsync to PutAsync instead but PutAsync does accept HttpRequestMessage type. I am trying to retain the information from the original request.

```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyFunc(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var url = "http://test.com/stuffgoeshere"

        UriBuilder forwardUri = new UriBuilder(url);
        request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                    var response = await client.PutAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                    return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http Method(Verb) is already in HttpResponseMessage in property Method and you can set it up or change if you need:

```
request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
```

That's why you can ease use SendAsync with your request:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyFunc(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var url = "http://test.com/stuffgoeshere";

    UriBuilder forwardUri = new UriBuilder(url);
    request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Or, if Method in HttpRequestMessage has already set up, just do SendAsync and it works.